# Removing all text left of the of a certain key that repeats itself

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a vector with a few texts:

```
 vec = c("gjljlfj <Joe", "fsdfs<sdfdsf<Mike", "David" , "dfsf<<<Don")
```

I am hoping to remove all text left of the LAST `<` (or the first if starting from the left side of the text), such as the new vector will look like this:

```
 newVec = c("Joe","Mike","David","Don")
```

Tried a few things but couldn't get it right. The next step would be to write function that starts from the last letter and checks if every letter is a `<` or not but I am sure there is a better solution (couldn't find it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with a regular expression:

```
regmatches(vec, regexpr("[^<]+$", vec))
```

`[^<]+` matches "one or more characters that are not '<'", and then `$` matches the end of the string.

If you have the `stringr` package installed this is just:

```
stringr::str_extract(vec, "[^<]+$")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sapply(strsplit(vec, "<"), function(x) tail(x, 1))
#[1] "Joe"   "Mike"  "David" "Don"
```

OR

```
substring(vec, 1 + sapply(gregexpr("<", vec), function(i) tail(i, 1)), nchar(vec))
#[1] "Joe"   "Mike"  "David" "Don"
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_extract_last` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last_regex(vec, "\\w+")
#[1] "Joe"   "Mike"  "David" "Don"
```